# How can I drop player inventory?

Tags: plugins, bukkit, inventory, items

I am kinda stuck with making a plugin...
This is my code I have:

```
Player player = (Player)event.getPlayer();
ItemStack item = new ItemStack( /* player.getInventory() */ /*  My problem here is how do i drop all items that or in my inventory (Some items might have enchantments!)  */);
World world = player.getWorld();
world.dropItem(player.getLocation(), item);
```

Does someone know how I drop all items that are in my inventory? Some items could have enchantments and cannot be removed while dropping.

Comment: Sorry :\ I'm quite new to stackoverflow :p Also i can't vote :(

Comment: don't worry: no harm done (and welcome!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about iterating over the players inventory and using dropItemNaturally?

```
for (ItemStack itemStack : player.getInventory()) {
    player.getWorld().dropItemNaturally(player.getLocation(), itemStack);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
for (ItemStack itemStack : player.getInventory()) {
    player.getWorld().dropItemNaturally(player.getLocation(), itemStack);
}
```

can return null if there is a slot in their inventory with no item in it.
I recommend this instead:

```
for (ItemStack itemStack : player.getInventory().getContents()) {
    player.getWorld().dropItemNaturally(player.getLocation(), itemStack);
}
for (ItemStack itemStack : player.getInventory().getArmorContents()) {
    player.getWorld().dropItemNaturally(player.getLocation(), itemStack);
}
```

In the for loops they only loop through the items in the inventory rather than the slots.

Comment: The code i use no din't return a null when it found any empty slots. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Why not just test for null, `if(itemStack == null) continue;` Instead of running away from null with more lines of code.